# MS Access to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, ms-access

I am developing an ASP.net application with Access database. I need to convert this Access database to Oracle. How can I do that?

I saw two options

1. Migrating the access database to Oracle through **MIGRATION WIZARD** in SQL developer
2. In Oracle, just creating a **new connection with existing MS Access database** and then converting to oracle.

Kindly let me know the best solution for this

thanks in advance,

Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY IT and then tell us.

My experience integrating all things oracle with all things microsoft has always been complicated, and a lot of manual intervention was required.

It also depends on the complexity of your existing access database, if it's only one table, then you can grab that table sql, correct it for nvarchar -> varchar2 fields and datapump the data into oracle.

If Access has 1000+ tables I would suggest getting a professional to do it. Any reasonable dba should handle it no problem.

Comment: @bOrg My Access database has 10 tables

Comment: manually create a schema script for tables to put them into oracle, then google how to data pump from Access to Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

The two choices you proffer could be rewritten like this:

1. Use an automated tool written by experts
2. Do it the hard way and figure it out for myself

This is a personal, even philosophical, choice.  Do you need to get the task done quickly?  Or do you want to learn something along the way?

Comment: I need the task to be done quickly but wish to do a perfect migration.

Comment: @ArjunBabu Why not use the migration wizard and use the time saved to check everything?

Comment: @Remou: I tried doing it, but during step 4 the target database (Access) is not getting displayed

Comment: In that case, rewrite your question including this relevant information. You question now becomes how to deal with a failure in automation and requires error codes and such like.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the solution at [Insert into from ms access to oracle db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873325/insert-into-from-ms-access-to-oracle-db/45623532#45623532)

You can customize the code based on your requirement. You can bundle the whole code into one class and prepare it as exe application.